# Asking Microsoft account password once authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a web app (c#, asp.net-core-mvc) for internal use in my company. Authentication is required through user Microsoft Accounts (either through Windows Authentication or Azure, both options are working).

The issue I'm having is that I have been asked to require password confirmation when executing certain actions.

I have looked in all the documentation I could find but have not been able to find anything about this use-case.
The one thing I have found out is that it's apparently impossible with Windows Authentication since you can't log someone out.

I have been able to prompt the login page by using `return Challenge();`, but it loops back on the login page when you login (or shows 401 error page if you cancel), and doesn't return anything I have been able to exploit.

With Azure it also loops right back to the login page.

It would in theory be possible through Azure authentication by logging the user out and then back in, but I haven't been able to send the user back to the right page with the right information after logging back in.

So if anyone has a solution I'm ready to try anything that uses Microsoft accounts (custom user accounts isn't really an option since it's an intranet application).

Comment: So I have finally found a way to do this. Using an LDAP query:
`PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);`

The big issue is that to use this you have to POST the password as a string so the password will be on server memory as plain text...